# Как поменять имя разработчика в Google PlayMarket?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Вот есть такое приложение на плей маркете

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте я выделил строку которую нужно поменять

Как это сделать из Google Play Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Заходите в [консоль](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) админа.
2. В левом меню "Настройки"
3. Изменяете поле "Имя разработчика"

Возможно потребуется немного времени, чтобы изменения вступили в силу.

Answer (score 0):

`Google Play Console -> Аккаунт разработчика -> Сведения об аккаунте -> Имя разработчика` (*до 50 символов*)

> Пользователи видят имя разработчика под названием приложения.
>   Изменения в имени разработчика проходят проверку в Google, которая
>   может занять до 7 дней.